# Unable to use CSS in HTML

Tags: html, css

For some odd reason I am not able to see the background change to black in testIndex.html. What I have is shown below:

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Test test</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using atom and these is no errors found in the styles.css... is there something I am doing wrong? I've read upon linking the CSS to HTML and by the looks of it I am doing it correctly. Just unable to see the changes made and both files have been saved too. I do have the styles.css in a different folder from the testIndex.html file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing relative file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
  there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
  moving forward

Answer (score 1):

Try this ../ is missing in you code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

Comment: Wow that worked, can you please explain why I needed those two dots prior to the `/css` folder?

Comment: you css folder is outside of Pizza Web folder. so u have to go one step back of Pizza Web folder.  to go one step back of folder you need ../

Comment: Definitely! Thanks you as well!

Answer (score 0):

You need one more detail in your link tag <>: 
    link type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css"

Comment: What kind of detail?

Answer (score 0):

add this  to your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

move the css folder to the pizza web folder and try